# Calculating with AutoWikiBrowser

Tags: regex, mediawiki, expr

I'm using regular expression in AutoWikiBrowser to replace the input of several values with just one value, such as this:

```
|value1=4
|value2=5
|value3=6
```

To this:

```
|value={{#expr:4+5+6}}
```

While the correct result does show on the page, it does not look good in the code itself, so I'm trying to find a way to make it the result only (in this case value=15) but so far no luck. Can someone help me with out showing how to make this possible?

P.S. I tried the search function but didn't find a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaWiki parser allows the templates can be subst'ed, ie replaced by their rendering. That's also true for parser functions call.

You can subst a template prefixing the template call by `subst:`.

`|value={{subst:#expr:4+5+6}}`

**Reference:** [Substitution on MediaWiki manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Substitution)

**Example:** [diff](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Utilisateur%3ADereckson%2FBrouillon&type=revision&diff=127229488&oldid=124654630) (the expression used is in the edit summary, the result in the diff)

Comment: I had used `subst:` previously when it comes to text but it didn't output properly, I'm glad it's not the same with numbers. Thanks!